# Tkinter game: Deleting instances

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a game for a competition using python and tkinter. So far, it's coming along nicely, as I have movement, and shooting... well sort of shooting. I am able to create the bullets and move them in the direction I want. However, I want to delete them when they go off the screen. That's the part I'm having trouble with. Below is my shooting code (which is bound to the left mouse button) and my movement code:

```
def shoot(self,e):
    theplayer=self.find_withtag("player")

    bullet=self.create_image([self.coords(theplayer)],image=self.playerUp,tag="bullet")
    self.bullets.append(bullet)

def movebullet(self):
    for bullet in self.bullets:
        x1,x2,y1,y2=self.bbox(bullet)

        if x1>1200:
            self.move(bullet,14,0)
        else:
            self.delete(bullet)
```

I thought the deleting code would work, but it gives me an error that says: 
"x1,x2,y1,y2=self.bbox(bullet)    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

I'm not sure what this means, and the shooting actually doesn't work with this. However, it worked before I tried deleting the bullets. I'd really appreciate anyone's help with this.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want x1>1200 instead of x1<1200?  I would think you would want the bullets to move while they are still on the screen.  Right now it looks like you are deleting every bullet as soon as it's fired.

Comment: woops good catch. now they actually move, but when they get to 1200, I get the same error as before

Comment: I think jwygralak's answer below is the right track for the NoneType

Comment: @ecline6: the `self` is needed because it appears this code is part of a class that inherits from tkinter's Canvas class.

Comment: It might be better to move the bullet out of sight instead of deleting it and creating a new one every time. There was (or is, not sure) some memory leak in the Tk canvas code, because identifiers cannot be fully reclaimed. So keep a look on your memory usage when you fire lots of bullets...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the code for your self.delete() method and the code for the class declaration that self is an instance of, it is hard to tell what, exactly, is wrong.

At a guess, I'd say you're deleting the instance object for the bullet that has moved offscreen, but you're not removing it from the list bullets[], so next time you call movebullet(self), it iterates through self.bullets and falls down when it tries to move
the now non-existant bullet.

try:

```
else:
    self.bullets.remove(bullet)
    self.delete(bullet)
```

Comment: After further consideration it appears that self is an instance of a Tkinter.Canvas widget, and each bullet is an image on that canvas. you're calling delete() on the bullet image which removes it from the canvas, but it still exists in your bullets list.

Comment: It works!!! Thanks a lot to everyone who contributed; this was a real lifesaver, seeing as I only have a few days left to make this game!

Comment: woops I forgot about that. gave an accept and upvote to you and bryan Oakley :)

Answer (score 1):

When you see `'NoneType' object is not iterable`, that means that you are trying to iterate over something that has the value `None`: you can't iterate over the single value `None`.

In the statement `x1,x2,y1,y2=self.bbox(bullet)`, you are iterating over the result of `self.bbox(bullet)`, and that function is apparently returning `None` under some circumstances. You'll want to get the value of this function and check that it is `not None` before you do anything with what it returns, such as splitting it into separate variables.

For example, you might want to change your code to:

```
bbox = self.bbox(bullet)
if bbox is not None:
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = bbox
    ...
```

Probably what is happening is that the first time a bullet goes off screen you're deleting it just fine, but you're forgetting to remove it from the list of bullets. The next time you iterate over the list of bullets, there are some items in the list that have already been deleted.

The fix should be simple: when you delete a bullet you'll want to remove it from the list.

Comment: honestly, I have no idea how to go about doing that :) I tried adding    "not (x1,x2,y1,y2==self.bbox(bullet))" to the     "if x1<1200" statement, and that gave me the same 'NoneType' error.